# Getting the end date from start date and duration in PROLOG

Tags: date, prolog, duration

I have just started to code in Prolog, and I cannot do what I would like to.
Basically I have 2 input:  a start date "2018/02/14" and a duration "99 days/months". I would like to know if there would be a way to predict the end date from this, in PROLOG:

```
date(X,Y,Z):-is_a_date(X),is_a_duration(Y),...
```

The main problem is about date format...

Any tips ?

Comment: *99 days/months*... I'm not sure what that means. Is it 99 days or 99 months?

Comment: @lurker : one or the other, it depends... Either the unit is "day", either the unit is "month".

Comment: How is your predicate expected to distinguish between days or months? You should at least determine how your predicate would be called.

Comment: You might want to read the SWI Prolog documentation reagarding [Dealing with time and date](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=timedate). Isabelle's answer gives a nice way of extracting month, day, and year information from a term. But then you'll need to deal with how many days in each month, whether you have a leap year, etc. This would all be handled for you in a date/time predicate library.

Answer (score 1):

> The main problem is about date format...

Prolog uses terms to model data. Terms can be atoms or numbers, or any compound terms obtained by applying functors or operators to other terms. `/` is an operator. So `2018/02/14` is a perfectly fine Prolog term:

```
?- Date = 2018/02/14.
Date = 2018/2/14.
```

This is different from most other programming languages, in which something like the above would be an *expression* that would be *evaluated* to a *value*. For example, entering `2018/2/14` into a Python prompt gives back `72.0714` because it thinks we want it to compute a number. But in Prolog the example above is *not* asking for a number; it simply says that `2018/02/14` is some *data* made up of three numbers separated by `/` signs.

To operate on Prolog data structures, we use unification:

```
?- Date = 2018/02/14, Date = Year/Month/Day.
Date = 2018/2/14,
Year = 2018,
Month = 2,
Day = 14.
```

We unified the date with another, similar term `Year/Month/Day`. Here, the leaves of the term are variables. Unification will bind these variables to the numbers in the date terms at the corresponding positions. That is all!

So (using meaningful variable and predicate names, which are *very important* in Prolog) you can write your predicate as:

```
startdate_duration_enddate(Year/Month/Day, Duration, EndDate) :-
    ... .
```